# Is there a way to enable network login in Wordpress with different domains?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have a Wordpress installation running on WAMP and a virtual host. The network has two sites, `site.local` and `subsite.site.local`, in other words, it's the subdomain installation.

Now, I noticed that I could change the domain of `subsite.site.local` to anything I liked, say, `anothersite.local` and as long as I had the correct configuration in my hosts file and httpd.conf, it would work, but only on the front end. When I try to login, Wordpress won't let me, but redirects me back to the login screen with no info or error.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this in wp-config.php:

```
$allowed_domains = array(
   'site.local',
   'anothersite.local'
);

$cookie_domain = (in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $allowed_domains)) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : $allowed_domains[0];
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $cookie_domain);
```

It checks if the user's domain is on the allowed domains list and adjust cookie domain on the fly to match it. It defaults to the first domain in the array if it doesn't match.